# correctness of sentence according to grammatically

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, phrase-requests

is these two sentences are correct (or not) to used them.
 ***The farm was used to produce produce.***
***i had to subject the subject to a series of test.***

Comment: Please edit your question to include _precisely_ what you think is not grammatical about the two sentences.

Comment: Hi Aqib, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are both correct (capitalize "I" in the second one, and pluralize "test").